# Getting the red border on validate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, dom-events

I am new to React and I am using normal Javascript to validate the form like this:

```
             <TextField
              label="Title"
              variant="outlined"
              size="small"
              name="Title"
              id="Title"
              placeholder="Enter the Title of the Best Practice"
              onChange={handleChange("Title")}
              defaultValue={values.Title}
              style={{ width: "80%" }}
            />
            <label id="title" style={{ visibility: "hidden" }}>
              Title must be atleast 3 characters long
            </label>
            <br />


continue = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (document.getElementById("Title").value.length < 3) {
      document.getElementById("title").style.visibility = "visible";
      // keep form from submitting
    } else {
      // else form is good let it submit, of course you will
      // probably want to alert the user WHAT went wrong.

      this.props.nextStep();
    }
  };
```

It shows the hidden label whenever the length is less than 3. However, I wanted to also highlight the text box red on length lesser than 3. How do we do that?

Answer (score 0):

First things first, why are you using javascript validations in your react app? What you are doing with javascript will update the Real DOM and in ReactJS we work with Virtual DOM. I suggest you to get through this article first: [Virtual DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html).

Another thing, Write a function for validation which will return true or false depending on what validations you want to provide. 
Bind a method on submit of the form, something like this:

```
submitForm(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if(this.validateValues()){
      this.setState({validated: true})
    }
    else
      this.setState({validated: false})
  }
```

Now, you can provide a className to your component or whatever you want to style accordingly

```
<Component className={this.state.validated ? 'redBorder' : 'originalClass'} />
```

And in CSS provide `.redBorder{ border-color: 'red' }`.

This is the one way to look at it.